# T-SQL Inserting Data Into Encrypted Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, ado

Based on a lot of research and [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/getting-started-with-always-encrypted-part-2) it appears my stored procedure below should work. However, I am getting this error whether I call directly in SQLServer17 or via ADO connection.

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varchar(255) encrypted
>   with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'AutoStripes_Machine_CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name =
>   'AutoStripes') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' is not
>   allowed.

I have `Column Encryption Setting = Enabled` and Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted checked in query options and I have the key on my machine I am using.

Stored Proc is below. I used cursor because it's impossible to encrypt temp tables AFAIK, so I thought to parameterize the VIN and where conditions to do update statements for those fields after records are inserted.

```
USE AutoSTripes;
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[loadVehicles] (@xmlString XML)

AS 

BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempVehs TABLE 
    (
        [ProductNo] [bigint],
        [VersionNo] [bigint],
        [DateAdded] [smalldatetime],
        [UserID] [varchar](255),
        [VehicleYear] [varchar](255),
        [Make] [varchar](255),
        [Model] [varchar](255),
        [VINNumber] [varchar](255), -- matches column that is encrypted
        -- .... more columns
        [VehicleSeqNo] [bigint],
        [CollDed] [varchar](255)
)

    INSERT INTO @tempVehs   
    SELECT
         XD.xTbl.value('./Product[1]', 'bigint') as ProductNo
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./Version[1]', 'bigint') as VersionNo
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./DateAdded[1]', 'smalldatetime') as DateAdded
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./UserID[1]', 'varchar(255)') as UserID
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./VehYear[1]', 'varchar(255)') as VehiclYear
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./Make[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Make
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./Model[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Model
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./Vin[1]', 'varchar(255)') as VinNumber
         -- ... more columns
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./SeqNo[1]', 'bigint') as VehicleSeqNo
         ,XD.xTbl.value('./CollDed[1]', 'varchar(255)') as CollDed
    FROM
        @xmlString.nodes('//VehicleList/Vehicle') AS XD(xTbl)

    INSERT INTO dbo.tVehicle
        (ProductNo, VersionNo, DateAdded, UserID, VehicleYear, Make, Model, GLCity, GLState, GLZip, VehicleType, Radius, Class, VehicleSeqNo, PIP, AddlPIP, MedPay, UMUIM, UMPD, OTCCov, OTCDed, ACVorStated, CollCov, CollDed) 
        SELECT
            ProductNo, VersionNo, DateAdded, UserID, VehicleYear, Make, Model, GLCity, GLState, GLZip,  VehicleType, Radius, Class, VehicleSeqNo, PIP, AddlPIP, MedPay, UMUIM, UMPD, OTCCov, OTCDed, ACVorStated, CollCov, CollDed
        FROM
            @tempVehs


    -- loop temp table and update VIN for each unique record    
    DECLARE @vin varchar(255)
    DECLARE @product bigint
    DECLARE @version bigint
    DECLARE @sequence bigint

    DECLARE @curs CURSOR

    BEGIN

        SET @curs = CURSOR FOR SELECT ProductNo, VersionNo,  VinNumber, VehicleSeqNo FROM @tempVehs
        OPEN @curs
        FETCH NEXT FROM @curs INTO @product, @version, @vin, @sequence

        Set @product = @product
        Set @version = @version
        Set @vin = @vin
        Set @sequence = @sequence

        UPDATE dbo.tVehicle SET VINNumber = @vin WHERE ProductNo = @product AND VersionNo = @version and VehicleSeqNo = @sequence

    END

    close @curs
    deallocate @curs

END

GO
```

What am I missing? Or is it just not possible at all?

Comment: Does your XML document contain encrypted data? If not then it will not work. SQL Server has no way to encrypt / decrypt data locally (the entire point of this technology)

Comment: it does not contain encrypted data @alex. Thanks. I was kind of thinking that that was the answer.